# How to get an EAR's full dependency tree?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Here's my use case: I want to get the full dependency tree of my EAR, with the following scopes: compile, runtime, test.

Unfortunately, Maven's Dependency Plugin only shows WARs as simple dependencies, without their transitive dependencies.

```
foo:bar-ear:ear:1.13.0-SNAPSHOT
+- foo:bar-web:war:1.13.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- foo:bar-web-service:war:1.13.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- foo:bar-business:ejb:1.13.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- foo:base-api:ejb:2.22.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
...
```

So I need to get the full dependency tree (including the WAR's dependencies) within a Maven plugin (using 3.0.4).

I tried it with Aether, but couldn't get the scopes right. Next I tried it with "old-style" Maven dependency resolution (peeking into the code of the Depencency Plugin), but `org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree` only works with a `MavenProject`, but I should tell the `DependencyGraphBuilder` to fetch the dependencies of any `Artifact`.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more accurate: What does ` within a Maven plugin (using 3.0.4).` mean? Is this your maven version or the maven-dependency-plugin or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get dependencies of WAR Artifact using Maven 2 API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364270/get-dependencies-of-war-artifact-using-maven-2-api)

Comment: @khmarbaise: I'm using Maven 3.0.4. I'm not quite sure what the accurate dependencies are for this version, this is what I have: maven-plugin-api 3.0.4, maven-core 3.0.4, maven-plugin-annotations 3.0, maven-dependency-tree 2.2

Comment: Ok I was not clear enough ;-(...First i meant the Maven version you are using which you answered (3.0.4)...furthermore which maven-dependency-plugin version you are using....

Comment: I'm using the version 2.8 of the maven-dependency-plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this is what worked with the Maven API. I used Google Guava and Apache Commons Lang 3, so if you're not familiar with these libraries, please ask.

```
/**
 * Gets all dependencies for an artifact, including the ones from WAR dependencies.
 * @param artifact The artifact
 * @return The dependencies, where the key is the artifactId and the values are all of its artifacts (different
 * versions, different scopes)
 * @throws MojoExecutionException if the dependencies can't be fetched
 */
protected Multimap<String, Artifact> getAllDependencies(final Artifact artifact) throws MojoExecutionException {
  Multimap<String, Artifact> projectDependencies = getDependencies(artifact);
  Multimap<String, Artifact> allDependencies = ArrayListMultimap.create(projectDependencies);

  for (Artifact dependency : projectDependencies.values()) {
    if (dependency.getType().equals("war")) {
      Multimap<String, Artifact> warDependencies = getDependencies(dependency);
      for (Artifact warArtifact : warDependencies.values()) {
        if (!containsArtifact(allDependencies, warArtifact)) {
          allDependencies.put(warArtifact.getArtifactId(), warArtifact);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return allDependencies;
}

/**
 * Gets the dependencies for an artifact.
 * @param artifact The artifact
 * @return The dependencies, where the key is the artifactId and the values are all of its artifacts (different
 * versions, different scopes)
 * @throws MojoExecutionException if the dependencies can't be fetched
 */
protected Multimap<String, Artifact> getDependencies(final Artifact artifact) throws MojoExecutionException {
  try {
    Artifact pomArtifact = this.repositorySystem.createProjectArtifact(artifact.getGroupId(),
        artifact.getArtifactId(), artifact.getVersion());
    MavenProject mavenProject = this.mavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(pomArtifact, this.remoteRepositories,
        this.localRepository);

    Multimap<String, Artifact> dependencies = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    DependencyNode rootNode = this.dependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(mavenProject, this.artifactFilter);

    CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor visitor = new CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor();
    rootNode.accept(visitor);

    for (DependencyNode dependencyNode : visitor.getNodes()) {
      Artifact dependencyArtifact = dependencyNode.getArtifact();
      if (!containsArtifact(dependencies, dependencyArtifact)) {
        dependencies.put(dependencyArtifact.getArtifactId(), dependencyArtifact);
      }
    }
    return dependencies;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new MojoExecutionException("Can't get dependencies for " + artifact, e);
  }
}

/**
 * Shows whether an artifact is contained in the given artifacts.
 * @param artifacts The artifacts
 * @param artifact The artifact to check
 * @return {@code true} if the artifact is contained, otherwise {@code false}
 */
protected boolean containsArtifact(final Multimap<String, Artifact> artifacts, final Artifact artifact) {
  String artifactId = artifact.getArtifactId();
  if (!artifacts.containsKey(artifactId)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    String coordinates = getCoordinates(artifact);
    for (Artifact existingArtifact : artifacts.get(artifactId)) {
      String existingCoordinates = getCoordinates(existingArtifact);
      if (coordinates.equals(existingCoordinates)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

/**
 * Gets the Maven coordinates for an artifact.
 * @param artifact The artifact
 * @return The Maven coordinates
 */
protected static String getCoordinates(final Artifact artifact) {
  List<String> parts = Lists.newArrayList(artifact.getGroupId(), artifact.getArtifactId(), artifact.getType(),
      artifact.getVersion(), artifact.getScope());
  return StringUtils.join(parts, ":");
}
```